# What will be the Xpath of this XML for PHP Dom Document use?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have an XML in the format,

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here I have to consider B and D are child of A, C is a child of B. But C and D have no child nodes.

I want to retrieve the last nodes of the hierarchy that doesn't have any more child nodes `<td>C</td> and <td>D</td>`etc which is inside `<tr>` and then replace the value of 'td' with 'th'. I am using this Xpath query `"//*[not(child::*)]"` but it retrieves all the leaf nodes like A and B as well. So what can be the best way to use my Xpath query so that I get that easily? Thanks in advance.

Edit: tags tr and td are only for representation purpose and are not used in the original code.

Comment: You can't have `<tr>` tags nested inside each other, that probably won't be helping DOMDocument do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem like you want to get all leaf nodes that have no following sibling:

```
//*[not(child::*) and not(following-sibling::*)]
```